# Problem using Alamofire and JSONDecoder to decode iTunes API

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

When I using Alamofire and JSONDecoder to decode iTunes API, I can not using this statement:

```
        let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?"
        NetworkImpl.getRequest(URLString: url, parameters: ["term": searchBar.text!, "entity": "software", "country": "cn", "limit": "200"]) { (response) in
        let jsonData = JSON(response)
        
        do{
            let text =  response.data // Here I can not using response.data this method.
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let newModel = try decoder.decode(NewModel.self, from: text!)
            print("------> \(newModel.resultCount)")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

I've made a AlamfireUtil and protocol Layer,here is AlamofireUtil:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum MethodType {
    case get
    case post
}

class AlamofireLayer{
    class func requestData(_ type : MethodType, URLString : String, parameters : [String : Any]? = nil, finishedCallback :  @escaping (_ result : Any) -> ()) {
        
        let method = type == .get ? HTTPMethod.get : HTTPMethod.post
        
        Alamofire.AF.request(URLString, method: method, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in
               
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                finishedCallback(json)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error:\(error)")
                break
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

And here is protocol layer and implemention layer:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

protocol NetworkUtil {
    static func postRequest(URLString: String, parameters : [String : Any]?, callback: @escaping (_ result: Any) -> ())
    static func getRequest(URLString: String, parameters : [String : Any]?,callback: @escaping (_ result: Any) -> ())
}

import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class NetworkImpl: NetworkUtil{
    
    static func getRequest(URLString: String, parameters: [String : Any]?, callback: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
        AlamofireLayer.requestData(MethodType.get, URLString: URLString, parameters: parameters) { result in
            callback(result)
        }
    }
    
    public static func postRequest(URLString: String, parameters: [String : Any]?, callback: @escaping (Any) -> ()) {
        AlamofireLayer.requestData(MethodType.post, URLString: URLString, parameters: parameters) { result in
            callback(result)
        }
    }
  
}
```

How to using JSONDecoder to decode iTunes's api?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  What happens?  What do you expect to happen?  What errors do you get? Why are you using `JSON(response)` and `response.data` with `JSONDecoder` when you already have `.responseJSON` in your AlamoFire?  You probably want `.responseData` See [ask].

Comment: Where in the World Is Carmen Sandiego?  Where is NewModel?

Comment: NewModel just a JSON to Swift model, which contanis baisc attrbutes.

Comment: I mean in XCode12 and Swift5 envirnment i can not usnig "response.data" this method

Comment: As I said, you are using `.responseJSON` in your `requestData` function, so `response` has already been decoded from JSON into an `Any` - If you want to use your `JSONDecoder` with a `Codable` struct then you want `.responseData` and then the `response` passed to the `getRequest` completion handler will be an instance of `Data` that you can pass to `JSONDecoder`.  Why not get rid of AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON and see if you can do what you want with the inbuilt `URLSessionDataTask` and `JSONDecoder`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try using URLSessionDataTask to request data directly. Btw, my first job is making a AppStore to show fully information, using saming api with Apple, it's too hard...

Comment: With Alamofire 5 and `responseDecodable` instead of `responseJSON` you can decode the stuff directly into a model. Forget `SwiftyJSON`. It has been a great help prior to Swift 4 but not anymore.

Comment: Yes, please just use `responseDecodable`.